# Ordering cursor pagination with Django-Rest

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I'm building an API with Django-Rest-Framework and set the cursor pagination - by default ordered by 'created' filter, what work really fine to some views.

But I have this one that I want order by other fields (last_update and visits). I put the ordering field in my view, but doesn't work.

```
class StationList(generics.ListAPIView):

    """
    List all stations.
    """
    ordering = ('-last_update', '-visits',)
    queryset = Station.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StationSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
```

That is part of my setting.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.CursorPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 12,
}
```

What I need to do to it works?

Comment: Keep in mind though that there are some restrictions on the ordering field you can use for `CursorPagination`: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#details-and-limitations

Answer (score 3):

Try listing your fields under `ordering_fields` as well, I think you still need to whitelist them for sorting:

```
ordering = ('-last_update', '-visits',)
ordering_fields= ('-last_update', '-visits',)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use a array instead a tuple.
try:

```
ordering = ['-last_update', '-visits']
```